# Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, author-number

In the header of my document I set the maximal author names to 2:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, maxbibnames=9, maxcitenames=2, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Now, when I cite texts with two authors, LaTeX gives me the following:

> (Author_A/ Author_B 2012: 232)

When I have three authors or more, LaTeX makes it:

> (Author_A/ Author_B et al. 2012: 232)

But I want LaTeX to just name the first author if there are more than two authors ... like this:

> (Author_A et al. 2012: 232)

Any tips on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Setting `maxcitenames=2` worked well with the `ieee` style but required to set also `mincitenames=1` since it was declared greater in this style.

Answer (score 165):

By default `biblatex` *will* truncate name lists exceeding `maxcitenames` to one author plus "et al." (`mincitenames=1`). However, `biblatex` will (also by default) *not* truncate if doing so would cause ambiguous citation keys, which I suspect is the case in your document. Compare the output of the following two examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{ABC01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author = {Author, A. and Duthor, D. and E},
  year = {2001},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{ABC01}.

Some text \autocite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only want one author in citation keys under all circumstances, use the option `uniquelist=false`. (Note that this may lead readers to the false conclusion that "Author et al." refers to the same author team.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author = {Author, A. and Duthor, D. and E},
  year = {2001},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{ABC01}.

Some text \autocite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was just the Information I needed. Thanx a lot!

Comment: §4.11.4 *Name Disambiguation* and in particular §4.11.4.2 *Lists of Names (`uniquelist`)* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) has additional information on what exactly goes on here and a few examples.