# biblatex is ignoring maxcitenames

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I am using the following line in my document:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=apa,maxcitenames=2,bibstyle=authoryear,doi=true,url=true]{biblatex}
```

However, `biblatex` ignores `maxcitenames`, and prints out every name, every time.

Is there are way to make `biblatex` stop ignoring `maxcitenames`?

Comment: ``maxcitenames`` only affects the citations in the doc. body, if you want to affect the bibliography use ``maxbibnames`` instead. Or just use ``maxnames=2`` and it will set both options to 2.

Comment: I know that. However, I found that if I set `citestyle=apa`, then `maxcitenames` does nothing. My solution was to use `citestyle=authoryear`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex

Comment: It doesn't mention the problem with apa styles, however.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default in `biblatex` is to use the `uniquelist` option. APA style also uses this. This option dynamically changes the `maxnames`/`minnames` settings in order to make citations unique. This is required by APA. APA style also applies APA rules regarding citation list truncation after the first cite within a paragraph. You are probably noticing the effects of these settings. APA style with `maxnames=2` is essentially not APA style – these settings are partly hard-coded into the style as a result ...

Comment: The sad thing is that I didn't actually want APA style, I wanted Harvard style, and I was following instructions from somewhere which said you could use APA and modify it to get Harvard. As you can see, I found it easier to modify the authoryear style.

Comment: Yes, it's always better to modify the default styles. Specialist styles like APA have some very tricky requirements which have to be coded into the style and are therefore not easy or impossible to change with standards biblatex package options. In fact I have added some such options to the package for some simple cases but after all, it's an APA style so adding options to make it non-APA compliant becomes suspect after a while ...

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to replace `citestyle=apa` with `citestyle=authoryear`. This fixes the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with `citestyle=authoryear`

Comment: For some reason, `citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=apa` still lets APA affect citation style. Removing the bibstyle fixes the citation problems.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only working solution, after `citestyle=authoryear` and `style=authoryear` did **not** work, was, to remove that parameter completely.

So, now my biblatex call is just:

```
\usepackage[minnames=5, maxnames=10, backend=biber,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
```

and it works correctly for me.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me: ```\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric-comp, minnames=5, maxnames=10]{biblatex}
```