# Biblatex - remove comma between year and pages

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to remove the comma between year and pages, e.g. :

(TAPLEY et al. 2004: 13-19) instead of

(TAPLEY et al. 2004, : 13-19)

It is my first time working with biblatex ,the code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle = apa, backend=biber, natbib=true, hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
and = {{\&}}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
pages = {{:}}}

\begin{document}
\parencite[13-19]{Tapley.2004}
\end{document}
```

And the Test.bib entry looks like below:

```
@article{Tapley.2004,
 author = {Tapley, B. D. and Bettadpur, S. and Watkins, M. and Reigber, C.},
 year = {2004},
 title = {The gravity recovery and climate experiment: Mission overview and early results},
 pages = {1-1000},
 volume = {31},
 number = {9},
 journal = {Geophysical Research Letters},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle = apa, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\space}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\begin{document}
\parencite[13-19]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The punctuation between the citation and its postnote is controlled by `\postnotedelim`. You simply want that to be a colon and a space. Then you want to suppress page numbers. This is better done by adjusting the field format instead of brutally redefining the `pages` bibstring.

A similar thing applies to the "and" that you want to replace with an ampersand. Redefine `finalnamedelim` and not the bibstring for `and`.

I have also changed `\mkbibnamelast` to `\mkbibnamefamily`, see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)
Furthermore it is a nice idea to use `\DeclareDelimFormat` for `nameyeardelim`.

Be warned that the combination `citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle = apa` does not conform to APA rules. Since `biblatex-apa` is purpose-built to implement the requirements of the APA it is usually not recommended to use it in documents with different requirements. `biblatex-apa` can be very hard to modify.

Lastly `hyperref=true` does not enable hyperlinks on its own. You still need to load `hyperref`. In fact `hyperref=true` has little advantage over the default `hyperref=auto`. The only difference between the two is that `true` emits a warning if `hyperref` is not loaded.

Comment: I have changed everything you suggested, perfect! I have to use this specific citation style and found it easiest to mix them. The bibliography only shows seven authors, not all of them. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Vivi `maxbibnames=999`? --- Probably not `bibstyle=apa` may need something else, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230452/35864

Comment: maxbibnames did not work but apamaxprtauth=999 did!