# bibstyle=apa6: how to list all authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I am using `bibstyle=apa6` that can only show 6 authors. How to show all authors?

```
\RequirePackage[bibstyle=apa6,sorting=ymdnt,uniquename=init,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography},title={Journal Articles},type=article]
```

Comment: Normally this would be controlled by `maxbibnames`, but `biblatex-apa6` uses a more complex name format, where you have to use the `biblatex-apa6` option `apamaxprtauth`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230452/35864.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It works right now. I appreciate your helps.