# How to have all authors in the bibliography instead of three dots?

Tags: biblatex

I used a paper as a citation in my work, and the bibliography does not list all authors; instead, it displays three dots (see the following Figure):[image]

I used the following package:

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  url=false,
  style=    apa6,
  maxnames=99,
  minnames=1,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=1,
  giveninits,
  citetracker=true,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex}
```

Did anybody have the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: that is the apa6 style. you could try apa7 https://apastyle.apa.org/blog/more-than-20-authors

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230452/35864 (the answer there was written back when `biblatex-apa` was 6th edition APA style, i.e. what is now `biblatex-apa6`, but it applies to both current `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-apa6`, the preset values for `apamaxprtauth` are just different).

Comment: Thank you! @moewe