# Make LaTeX not spell out authors when two similar references exist

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am citing a lot of articles from the same research groups, but with tiny changes to the author lists. To differentiate between these references, biblatex chooses to spell out the authors in my in-text references to avoid ambiguity. However, I would rather like to have biblatex add a letter behind the year.

In short, this:

```
Some claim (Firstauthor et al 2015a; Firstauthor et al 2015b).
```

instead of this:

```
Some claim (Firstauthor & Secondauthor 2015; Firstauthor & Randomauthor 2015).
```

Is this easily fixed?

Comment: See if [Distinguishing with labels a,b,... instead of another author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175533) solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, the solution fixes my problem. Thank you for providing the link.

Comment: Good to hear. We'll close as a duplicate then.