# Biblatex citation problem - disambiguate by year only

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, author-number

I am trying to switch to biber from bibtex8 and I really need the apalike settings.

I am calling

```
\usepackage[
uniquename=false,
maxcitenames=2, 
mincitenames=1,
maxitems=2,
minitems=1,
natbib=true,
url=false,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
eprint=false,
backref=true,
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp,
]{biblatex}
```

and I get correct citations in the text like:
Bateman and Langford (1997)

but then I get 
Bateman, Langford, et al. (2000)
Bateman, Day, et al. (2006)
Bateman, Mace, et al. (2011)

and these are wrong. I am getting extremely frustrated since the maximum number of authors set is 2 and that should reduce to 1 + et al. I think what is happening is that it is saying Bateman has many papers (which he does) and it must separate them based on authors. What is should read is this:

Bateman et al. (2000)
Bateman et al. (2006)
Bateman et al. (2011)

and if there are muliples it should read
Bateman et al. (2000)
Bateman et al. (2000a)

while in a block I would expect (Bateman et al. 2000, 2000a)

Is there an apalike set of settings which will produce the exact (and quite correct) output that I got from bibtex+apalike using biblatex and biber?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex

Comment: I don't believe it. It actually worked. I cannot tell you how long I spent trying to figure out how to even google this question. Thank you so much.

Comment: there's also a package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa you might check out.