# use authoryearstyle in biblatex with year label letter for same first author

Tags: biblatex

I use `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}` for my bibliography, which works perfectly fine. However, when an author appears multiple times biblatex also shows the name of the second author before printing the year. This even happens in cases of different year entries. How is it possible to suppress the printing of the second author and to label the citation with the year 2015a, 2015b instead?

Here is my bibfile:

```
@article{first,
  title={Paper 1},
  author={Ambigous, Alan and John Doe and others}, 
  year={2015},
}

@article{second,
  title={Paper 2},
  author={Ambigous, Alan and Richard Roe and others}, 
  year={2015},
}

@article{third,
  title={Paper 3},
  author={Miles, Juliane and Paul Waterman and others}, 
  year={2000},
}

@article{fourth,
  title={Paper 4},
  author={Miles, Juliane and John Smith and others}, 
  year={1999},
}
```

Comment: As acknowledged by the OP (in the comment to the answer below) this is solved by `uniquelist=false`, `uniquename=false`. So I will vote to close as a duplicate of [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864).

Answer (score 0):

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{quorum.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{first, second, third, fourth}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where `quorum.bib` is the bib file you wrote I get

> Ambigous, Doe, et al. 2015a,b; Miles, Smith, et al. 1999, 2000

That is, 2015a, 2015b as you requested. So I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I wanted to cite the sources independently with \cite{first} \cite{second} \cite{third} and \cite{fourth}, which did not work with the desired output. I specified uniquename=false and uniquelist=false, which in fact does work now.

Comment: Using `\cite{first} \cite{second}` in my document above yields `Ambigous, Doe, et al. 2015a Ambigous, Roe, et al. 2015b`. For me it's still not clear what problem you are describing, probably because you never made a MWE.

Comment: @QuorumSensing du you want something like "Ambigous et al. 2015a,b; Miles et al. 1999, 2000 Ambigous et al. 2015a Ambigous et al. 2015b"?