# Set limit on number of authors in citation call-out when using the IEEEtranN bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

I know the thread [Set limit to one author when using “et al.” in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/13173) but this thread is about BibTeX.

Code where bibliography in BibTeX

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} % I think not necessary

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Cesarean Section and Epidemiology}

\begin{itemize}
\item First Modern C-section by Ferdinand Adolf Kehrer 1881. \cite{history_c_section}
\item Surgical procedure where one or more incisions are made through a mother's abdomen and uterus to deliver one or more babies.
\item 2012, 23M globally. \cite{molina} 10-15\% of all. \cite{who_c_section} but >19\% better? 
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{task}

\end{frame}
```

Task.bib

```
@book{ history_c_section,
  author = "Dadebo, Dr. Benjamin",
  year = 2012,
  title = "Begat By God: Understanding the Concept of Being Born Again",
  publisher = "Xlibris Corporation",
  pages = "31–",
  note = "ISBN 978-1-4771-0612-9"
}

@article{ who_c_section,
  author = "WHO",
  title = "{WHO Statement on Caesarean Section Rates}",
  year = 2015,
  note= "[Online; accessed 7-Feb-2015]"
}

@article{ molina,
  author = "Molina, G and Weiser, TG and Lipsitz, SR and Esquivel, MM and Uribe-Leitz, T and Azad, T and Shah, N and Semrau, K and Berry, WR and Gawande, AA and Haynes, AB",
  year = 2015,
  title = "{Relationship Between Cesarean Delivery Rate and Maternal and Neonatal Mortality}",
  journal = "JAMA 314",
  volume = "21",
  pages = "2263–70"
}
```

Output in one page where you see the problem with Molina

[image]

### Complication After adding `\usepackage{natbib}` in beginning

Mico's solution solves the initial bug but causes a complication.
I get the strange top-bar *references* in each slide

[image]

Why is there the *references* top-bar?

---

How can you limit the amount of authors in the bibliography of Beamer?

Comment: Your write-up is a bit confusing. You mention an earlier posting that uses `biblatex`, yet your example code would not appear to make use of `biblatex` at all and, instead, use BibTeX. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico The other thread is in `biblatex`. This one is in BibTeX.

Comment: Why even mention a biblatex-related thread that's of no relevance for the problem at hand?

Comment: @Mico Just to compare two similar cases with two different packages.

Comment: You ask, "Why is there ... "References" [in the] top-bar?" Because the beamer theme you've chosen places the titles of numbered and unnumbered section headers in the top-bar. The instruction `\bibliography` generates an unnumbered section header named, you guessed it, "References". Which beamer theme(s) do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style -- hint: the final `N` in `IEEEtranN` stands for "natbib" -- you should load the `natbib` citation management package. Once you do that, you'll get the desired, i.e., truncated list of authors in the citation call-outs generated by `\cite`.

Comment: I got a complication after adding `\usepackage{natbib}` in the beginning. I updated the body.

Comment: The "References" label is generated by the `\bibliography` instruction.  If you don't want the label to show up, you'll need to change one or more beamer themes. I suggest that you start with `\useouthertheme{default}` and see if you like the result. If it's not to your liking, and if you can't find a suitable theme in chapter 16 of the `beamer` user guide, may I suggest that you post a *new* query? The theme issue is not exactly closely related to the issue of the proper usage of the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style.

Comment: Yes. I extended the thread here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296032/13173

Comment: @Masi - Thanks for posting a new query. I've left a comment there, asking you to state which `beamer` theme you use. As posted, the MWE produces no bar along the top of the page.

Comment: Can you force two authors go to `et al` mode too? Now `et al` starts only if there are three authors or more when you cite.

Comment: @masi - It could be done, but it would require quite a bit of (re)programming of some of the functions in `IEEEtranN.bst`. It would also be rather unusual, typographically speaking. As it wouldn't actually save that much space -- compare "Brown and Smith (2009)" vs. "Brown et al. (2009)", I wouldn't recommend doing it.