# How to Suppress Top-bar of BibTeX in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I know the thread [How to hide references from navigation bar in beamer class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187877/13173)
I do not want to hide it but suppress it such that it does not come out.
I got this complication in this thread [Set limit on number of authors in citation call-out when using the IEEEtranN bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295984/13173).

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\useoutertheme{Berlin} % I think not necessary because otherwise just default which is fine
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Cesarean Section and Epidemiology}

\begin{itemize}
\item First Modern C-section by Ferdinand Adolf Kehrer 1881. \cite{history_c_section}
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{task}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

task.bib

```
@book{ history_c_section,
  author = "Dadebo, Dr. Benjamin",
  year = 2012,
  title = "Begat By God: Understanding the Concept of Being Born Again",
  publisher = "Xlibris Corporation",
  pages = "31–",
  note = "ISBN 978-1-4771-0612-9"
}
```

I think the top-bar is handled like section by beamer. Normally, I do `\section*{My Name is Masi}` to hide the numbering. Probably, a similar procedure could work somehow with BibTeX.

Complication

[image]

How to Suppress the top bar *refereces* in BibTeX of Beamer?

Comment: Your MWE currently doesn't select any `beamer` "themes"; thus, no bar along the top of the page is being generated by the MWE. Please edit your MWE to make it generate an info bar along the top of the page.

Comment: @Mico Done. See the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add the instruction

```
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

after loading the "Berlin" main document theme.

For more information on "outer themes" (including alternatives to "infolines"), see section 16.2 of the user guide of the `beamer` package.

You may also want to consider switching the main document theme of your `beamer` document. For instance, the `Rochester` theme has no navigational sidebars anywhere, but is otherwise somewhat similar to the `Berlin` theme.