# Modifying bibliography with biblatex/biber (apa-style) location+publisher+doi

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style, doi

Concerning the citation and bibliography of my thesis, some issues I could solve myself, with others I got help. But here is where I'm stuck:

If there is a book or bookchapter that's got a doi, location+publisher won't show up (for example check Backhaus et al.; Castells; Revelle/Condon), but without doi, location+publisher show up (for example check Foucault. Is there a possibility to change that? It should look like: »location: publisher. doi:12345« (for example »Oxford: Wiley-Blackwell. doi:10.1002/9781444319514«).

Maybe you also notice, that in the case of Castells the volume number is not shown, too, whereas for Revelle/Condon without doi it is shown, but in the arabic number, not the roman number (even if that's the information of the bibentry). In the case of Foucault the volume number is not shown although there's no doi. Could that be fixed, too?

Maybe this has got to do with changes to an APA feature? Or does it have to do with the zotero-import of my bibentries? See, before this problem happened, all books would be imported as »@book« (Backhaus et al.), whereas now it's »@mvbook« (Foucault).

I'm using APA-Style with biber as backend for biblatex. All help is much appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,toc=listof]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % Sprachpakete
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Direkte Eingabe von Umlauten
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Worttrennung bei Umlauten
\usepackage{microtype}              % Verbesserter Randausgleich
% Anführungszeichen
\usepackage[
 babel,
 german=quotes,
 german=guillemets
 ]{csquotes}

% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
% Bibliographie
% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

\usepackage[
    style           = apa,
    citestyle       = authoryear,
    citetracker     = false,    % immer Kurzform (= ab 3 Autoren et al.)
    uniquelist      = false,    % immer nur 1. Autor + et al.
    sorting         = nyt,
    sortcites       = true,
    autocite        = inline,
    maxbibnames     = 99,
    maxcitenames    = 2,
    backend         = biber,
    bibliography    = totoc,
    isbn            = false,
    doi             = true,
    urldate         = short
    ]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
}

% increase vertical space between bibliography items.
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.3ex}
\setlength\bibnamesep{1.0ex}

% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
% Zitation
% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

% remove comma in (Beadle and Tautum, 1941) This applies to citation only
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

% change delimiters
% since the delimiters use several contexts, some format clearing needs to happen
\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{\,/\,}
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{multinamedelim}

% Umbrüche in URL und DOI bei Zahlen zulassen
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}  % allow breaks at numbers

% Reihen in Bibliographie
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

% name sort always last, first
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given}


% Anpassungen um Schriftenreihe mit Nummer vor Ort und Verlag zu platzieren
\renewbibmacro*{addinfo}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{edition}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{chapter}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{volumes}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{pages}\AND%
              \(\iffieldundef{volume}\OR\boolean{bbx:volseen}\)}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibopenparen}%
   \printfield{edition}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{chapter}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \notbool{bbx:volseen}%
     {\iffieldundef{volume}{}{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \iffieldundef{part}{}{\printfield{part}}}{}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{volumes}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit{}%
   \printtext{\bibcloseparen}%
   \newunit}}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
           \iffieldundef{volume}
         {}
         {\setunit{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
          \printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}%
          \setunit{\adddot\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{maintitle}\AND\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{in}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \iffieldundef{volume}
     {}
     {\setunit{\addspace\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \printfield{part}%
      \setunit{\adddot\addspace}}}%
\usebibmacro{booktitle}}}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{number}}
  {}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
% * * *

% Eintragsart Bericht (report) Anpassung
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{number}    {\bibcpstring{number}~\apanum{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{apa:reportnum}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}}

\xpatchbibdriver{report}
  {\printlist{institution}}
  {}
  {}{}
\newbibmacro*{location+institution}{%
  \printlist[default][1-1]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \newunit}
\xpatchbibdriver{report}
  {\usebibmacro{location+publisher}}
  {\usebibmacro{location+institution}}
  {}{}

% bei allen Eintragsarten andere Editortypen missachten
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \iffieldequalstr{editortype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editor}\typeout{delete editor (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editoratype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editora}\typeout{delete editora (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editorbtype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editorb}\typeout{delete editorb (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editorctype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editorc}\typeout{delete editorc (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
}

% Angabe "S." vor Seitenzahlen bei Journals
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

% Subtitel nach Titel mit "––"
%\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addspace\textemdash\space}

% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
% Quellen
% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Backhaus.etal_2016,
  langid    = {ngerman},
  location  = {Berlin},
  title     = {Multivariate Analysemethoden \textemdash{} Eine anwendungsorientierte Einf{\"u}hrung},
  edition   = {14., {\"u}berarb. u. akt. Aufl.},
  isbn      = {978-3-662-46075-7},
  publisher = {Springer Gabler},
  date      = {2016},
  author    = {Backhaus, Klaus and Erichson, Bernd and Plinke, Wulff and Weiber, Rolf},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-662-46076-4}
}
@report{Revelle_2017b,
  langid      = {english},
  location    = {Evanston, IL},
  title       = {How To: {Use} the psych package for Factor Analysis and data reduction},
  url         = {http://personality-project.org/r/psych/HowTo/factor.pdf},
  institution = {Department of Psychology, Northwestern University},
  urldate     = {2018-07-01},
  date        = {2017},
  author      = {Revelle, William}
}
@incollection{Revelle.Condon_2018,
  langid       = {english},
  location     = {Chichester},
  title        = {Reliability},
  volume       = {II},
  isbn         = {978-1-118-48977-2},
  booktitle    = {The Wiley Handbook of Psychometric Testing \textemdash{} A Multidisciplinary Reference on Survey, Scale and Test     Development},
  publisher    = {J.~Wiley \& Sons},
  date         = {2018},
  pages        = {709-749},
  author       = {Revelle, William and Condon, David M.},
  editor       = {Irwing, Paul and Booth, Tom and Hughes, David J.},
  doi          = {10.1002/9781118489772.ch23}
}
@article{Wright.Herrington_2011,
  langid       = {english},
  title        = {Problematic Standard Errors and Confidence Intervals for Skewness and Kurtosis},
  volume       = {43},
  issn         = {1554-3528},
  doi          = {10.3758/s13428-010-0044-x},
  number       = {1},
  journaltitle = {Behavior Research Methods},
  date         = {2011},
  pages        = {8-17},
  author       = {Wright, Daniel B. and Herrington, Joshua A.}
}
@mvbook{Castells_2010,
  langid = {english},
  location = {{Oxford}},
  title = {The Information Age \textemdash{} Economy, Society, and Culture, Vol. 1: The Rise of the Network Society},
  edition = {2. Aufl.},
  volume = {I},
  isbn = {978-1-4443-1951-4},
  volumes = {III},
  publisher = {{Wiley-Blackwell}},
  date = {2010},
  author = {Castells, Manuel},
  doi = {10.1002/9781444319514}
}
@mvbook{Foucault_2004,
  langid = {ngerman},
  location = {{Frankfurt am Main}},
  title = {Geschichte der Gouvernmentalit{\"a}t, Bd. 2: Die Geburt der Biopolitik \textemdash{} Vorlesung am Coll{\`e}ge de France 1978\textendash{}1979},
  volume = {II},
  isbn = {978-3-518-58393-7},
  shorttitle = {Die Geburt der Biopolitik},
  volumes = {II},
  pagetotal = {517},
  series = {Taschenbuch Wissenschaft},
  publisher = {{Suhrkamp}},
  date = {2004},
  author = {Foucault, Michel},
  editor = {Sennelart, Michel},
  translator = {Brede-Konersmann, Claudia and Schr{\"o}der, J{\"u}rgen}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% ******************* T E X T *******************%
\begin{document}
\noindent Source 1: \cite[8]{Wright.Herrington_2011}\\
Source 2: \cite{Revelle_2017b}\\
Source 3: \cite{Backhaus.etal_2016}\\
Source 4: \cite{Castells_2010}\\
Source 5: \cite{Revelle.Condon_2018}\\
Source 6: \cite{Foucault_2004}

\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: As they are currently given there is no point in displaying the `volume` field for `Castells_2010` and `Foucault_2004`. It is already implicit in the `title` field. As a matter of fact I don't think they should be `@mvbook`s, they should just be `@book` because they refer to one specific book/volume and not the entire collection of volumes (which would be an `@mvbook`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have said this before, but for the benefit of other readers: It is usually a bad idea to try to modify specialised styles like `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-chicago` so heavily. These styles were specifically written to conform to very strict (and sometimes complicated and slightly inconsistent) rules of an authoritative style guide. That means that the code is much more complicated than the standard styles, which were meant to be modified as needed. **For future project I strongly advise to build your customised style upon one of the standard styles (probably `authoryear` in this case) `\begin{advertising}` or upon one of the style of my [`biblatex-ext` family](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) `\end{advertising}`**

It is a feature of APA style that `location` and `publisher` are dropped if the DOI is present for chapters like `@incollection` or `@inbook`. That can be turned off by redefining the macro `location+publisher`.

The `volume` field in `Castells_2010` and `Foucault_2004` is not shown because the entries lack a `maintitle` field. Usually the `maintitle`+`volume` are used together like

```
@book{Castells_2010,
  langid       = {english},
  location     = {Oxford},
  maintitle    = {The Information Age},
  mainsubtitle = {Economy, Society, and Culture},
  title        = {The Rise of the Network Society},
  volume       = {I},
  edition      = {2. Aufl.},
  isbn         = {978-1-4443-1951-4},
  volumes      = {III},
  publisher    = {Wiley-Blackwell},
  date         = {2010},
  author       = {Castells, Manuel},
  doi          = {10.1002/9781444319514}
}
@book{Foucault_2004,
  langid     = {ngerman},
  location   = {Frankfurt am Main},
  maintitle  = {Geschichte der Gouvernmentalit{\"a}t},
  volume     = {II},
  title      = {Die Geburt der Biopolitik},
  subtitle   = {Vorlesung am Coll{\`e}ge de France 1978\textendash{}1979},
  isbn       = {978-3-518-58393-7},
  shorttitle = {Die Geburt der Biopolitik},
  volumes    = {II},
  pagetotal  = {517},
  series     = {Taschenbuch Wissenschaft},
  publisher  = {Suhrkamp},
  date       = {2004},
  author     = {Foucault, Michel},
  editor     = {Sennelart, Michel},
  translator = {Brede-Konersmann, Claudia and Schr{\"o}der, J{\"u}rgen}
}
```

(note that I also split up fields into `...title` and `...subtitle` where appropriate).

Since both entries refer only to one (pyhsical) book of a a multi-volume project, `@book` is the appropriate entry type. I would use `@mvbook` only if I wanted to refer to the entire multi-volume work at once for example

```
@mvbook{knuth:ct,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  date         = {1984/1986},
  volumes      = 5,
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
}
```

Similarly `volumes` (in plural) only makes sense if a work consists of several volumes, and that will always be a `@mvbook`/`@mvcollection`. Your entries, however, refer to just one book and so `volumes` is not really needed (except as an volume 2 of 3 sort of thing, which I don't think any style does).

The two code-level changes have been marked with today's date `2018-09-24` so they are easier to spot.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,toc=listof]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % Sprachpakete
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Direkte Eingabe von Umlauten
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Worttrennung bei Umlauten
\usepackage{microtype}              % Verbesserter Randausgleich
% Anführungszeichen
\usepackage[
 babel,
 german=quotes,
 german=guillemets
 ]{csquotes}

% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
% Bibliographie
% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

\usepackage[
    style           = apa,
    citestyle       = authoryear,
    citetracker     = false,    % immer Kurzform (= ab 3 Autoren et al.)
    uniquelist      = false,    % immer nur 1. Autor + et al.
    sorting         = nyt,
    sortcites       = true,
    autocite        = inline,
    maxbibnames     = 99,
    maxcitenames    = 2,
    backend         = biber,
    bibliography    = totoc,
    isbn            = false,
    doi             = true,
    urldate         = short
    ]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
}

% increase vertical space between bibliography items.
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.3ex}
\setlength\bibnamesep{1.0ex}

% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
% Zitation
% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

% remove comma in (Beadle and Tautum, 1941) This applies to citation only
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

% change delimiters
% since the delimiters use several contexts, some format clearing needs to happen
\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{\,/\,}
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{multinamedelim}

% Umbrüche in URL und DOI bei Zahlen zulassen
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}  % allow breaks at numbers

% Reihen in Bibliographie
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}

% name sort always last, first
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given}


% Anpassungen um Schriftenreihe mit Nummer vor Ort und Verlag zu platzieren
\renewbibmacro*{addinfo}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{edition}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{chapter}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{volumes}\AND%
              \iffieldundef{pages}\AND%
              \(\iffieldundef{volume}\OR\boolean{bbx:volseen}\)}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibopenparen}%
   \printfield{edition}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{chapter}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \notbool{bbx:volseen}%
     {\iffieldundef{volume}{}{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \iffieldundef{part}{}{\printfield{part}}}{}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{volumes}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit{}%
   \printtext{\bibcloseparen}%
   \newunit}}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
           \iffieldundef{volume}
         {}
         {\setunit{\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
          \printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}%
          \setunit{\adddot\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{maintitle}\AND\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{in}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \iffieldundef{volume}
     {}
     {\setunit{\addspace\global\booltrue{bbx:volseen}}%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \printfield{part}%
      \setunit{\adddot\addspace}}}%
\usebibmacro{booktitle}}}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{number}}
  {}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{collection}
  {\printfield{series}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {}{}
% * * *

% 2018-09-24:1
\renewbibmacro*{location+publisher}{%
  \printlist[default][1-1]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit}

% Eintragsart Bericht (report) Anpassung
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{number}    {\bibcpstring{number}~\apanum{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{apa:reportnum}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}}

\xpatchbibdriver{report}
  {\printlist{institution}}
  {}
  {}{}
\newbibmacro*{location+institution}{%
  \printlist[default][1-1]{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \newunit}
\xpatchbibdriver{report}
  {\usebibmacro{location+publisher}}
  {\usebibmacro{location+institution}}
  {}{}

% bei allen Eintragsarten andere Editortypen missachten
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \iffieldequalstr{editortype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editor}\typeout{delete editor (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editoratype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editora}\typeout{delete editora (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editorbtype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editorb}\typeout{delete editorb (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
  \iffieldequalstr{editorctype}{redactor}
    {\global\clearname{editorc}\typeout{delete editorc (type: redactor) in \thefield{citekey}}}{}%
}

% Angabe "S." vor Seitenzahlen bei Journals
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

% 2018-09-24:2
% Subtitel nach Titel mit "––"
\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addspace\textemdash\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volumes}{#1 \bibstring{volumes}}
\renewbibmacro*{maintitle}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{maintitle}\AND\iffieldundef{mainsubtitle}}
    {}
    {\printtext[maintitle]{%
       \printfield[apacase]{maintitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[apacase]{mainsubtitle}}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}
  \printfield{maintitleaddon}%
  \addcolon\space}


% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
% Quellen
% ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Backhaus.etal_2016,
  langid    = {ngerman},
  location  = {Berlin},
  title     = {Multivariate Analysemethoden},
  subtitle  = {Eine anwendungsorientierte Einf{\"u}hrung},
  edition   = {14., {\"u}berarb. u. akt. Aufl.},
  isbn      = {978-3-662-46075-7},
  publisher = {Springer Gabler},
  date      = {2016},
  author    = {Backhaus, Klaus and Erichson, Bernd and Plinke, Wulff and Weiber, Rolf},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-662-46076-4}
}
@report{Revelle_2017b,
  langid      = {english},
  location    = {Evanston, IL},
  title       = {How To: {Use} the psych package for Factor Analysis and data reduction},
  url         = {http://personality-project.org/r/psych/HowTo/factor.pdf},
  institution = {Department of Psychology, Northwestern University},
  urldate     = {2018-07-01},
  date        = {2017},
  author      = {Revelle, William}
}
@incollection{Revelle.Condon_2018,
  langid       = {english},
  location     = {Chichester},
  title        = {Reliability},
  volume       = {II},
  isbn         = {978-1-118-48977-2},
  booktitle    = {The Wiley Handbook of Psychometric Testing},
  booksubtitle = {A Multidisciplinary Reference on Survey, Scale and Test Development},
  publisher    = {J.~Wiley \& Sons},
  date         = {2018},
  pages        = {709-749},
  author       = {Revelle, William and Condon, David M.},
  editor       = {Irwing, Paul and Booth, Tom and Hughes, David J.},
  doi          = {10.1002/9781118489772.ch23}
}
@article{Wright.Herrington_2011,
  langid       = {english},
  title        = {Problematic Standard Errors and Confidence Intervals for Skewness and Kurtosis},
  volume       = {43},
  issn         = {1554-3528},
  doi          = {10.3758/s13428-010-0044-x},
  number       = {1},
  journaltitle = {Behavior Research Methods},
  date         = {2011},
  pages        = {8-17},
  author       = {Wright, Daniel B. and Herrington, Joshua A.}
}
@book{Castells_2010,
  langid       = {english},
  location     = {Oxford},
  maintitle    = {The Information Age},
  mainsubtitle = {Economy, Society, and Culture},
  title        = {The Rise of the Network Society},
  volume       = {I},
  edition      = {2},
  isbn         = {978-1-4443-1951-4},
  publisher    = {Wiley-Blackwell},
  date         = {2010},
  author       = {Castells, Manuel},
  doi          = {10.1002/9781444319514}
}
@book{Foucault_2004,
  langid     = {ngerman},
  location   = {Frankfurt am Main},
  maintitle  = {Geschichte der Gouvernmentalit{\"a}t},
  volume     = {II},
  title      = {Die Geburt der Biopolitik},
  subtitle   = {Vorlesung am Coll{\`e}ge de France 1978\textendash{}1979},
  isbn       = {978-3-518-58393-7},
  shorttitle = {Die Geburt der Biopolitik},
  pagetotal  = {517},
  series     = {Taschenbuch Wissenschaft},
  publisher  = {Suhrkamp},
  date       = {2004},
  author     = {Foucault, Michel},
  editor     = {Sennelart, Michel},
  translator = {Brede-Konersmann, Claudia and Schr{\"o}der, J{\"u}rgen}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% ******************* T E X T *******************%
\begin{document}
Source 1: \cite[8]{Wright.Herrington_2011}\par
Source 2: \cite{Revelle_2017b}\par
Source 3: \cite{Backhaus.etal_2016}\par
Source 4: \cite{Castells_2010}\par
Source 5: \cite{Revelle.Condon_2018}\par
Source 6: \cite{Foucault_2004}

\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

[image: Backhaus, K./Erichson, B./Plinke, W./Weiber, R. (2016). Multivariate Analysemethoden —Eine anwendungsorientierte Einführung (14., überarb. u. akt. Aufl.). Berlin: Springer Gabler.doi:10.1007/978-3-662-46076-4//Castells, M. (2010). The Information Age — Economy, Society, and Culture: Bd. 1. The Rise ofthe Network Society (2. Aufl.). Oxford: Wiley-Blackwell. doi:10.1002/9781444319514//Foucault, M. (2004). Geschichte der Gouvernmentalität: Bd. 2. Die Geburt der Biopolitik —Vorlesung am Collège de France 1978–1979 (M. Sennelart, Hrsg. & C. Brede-Konersmann/J.Schröder, Übers.). Taschenbuch Wissenschaft. Frankfurt am Main: Suhrkamp.//Revelle, W. (2017). How To: Use the psych package for Factor Analysis and data reduction.Evanston, IL: Department of Psychology, Northwestern University. Zugriff 01.07.2018 unterhttp://personality-project.org/r/psych/HowTo/factor.pdf//Revelle, W./Condon, D. M. (2018). Reliability. In P. Irwing/T. Booth/D. J. Hughes (Hrsg.),The Wiley Handbook of Psychometric Testing — A Multidisciplinary Reference on Survey,Scale and Test Development (Bd. 2, S. 709–749). Chichester: J. Wiley & Sons. doi:10.1002/9781118489772.ch23//Wright, D. B./Herrington, J. A. (2011). Problematic Standard Errors and Confidence Intervalsfor Skewness and Kurtosis. Behavior Research Methods, 43(1), S. 8–17. doi:10.3758/s13428-010-0044-x]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code changes! Just to understand, so maybe I could do it properly: if it's not a good idea to change biblatex-apa to this extent, which would be the better way?

Comment: @Leandro I would have started from a standard style like `authoryear` (or maybe from one of my styles in `biblatex-ext`). But I guess you are in too deep already.

Comment: I like the idea of the biblatex-ext bundle. If there's enough time left, I will start from scratch and use that. Thank's for the advice.