# Remove space between authors in citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I was wondering if I can remove the space between the authors in citation.
[image: Example]

I edited my citation style this way:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, maxcitenames=3,natbib=true,doi=false]{biblatex}
\LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet}                     %Jahr in Klammern
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Doppelpunkt statt Punkt
\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{\,/\,} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{multinamedelim}
```

Now I'm almost done but I don't want the space between the slashes.

Anyone an idea? Thank you. :D

Comment: I'd guess you only need to replace `\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{\,/\,}` by `\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{/}`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Do you want to type up a short answer here, so we can mark this question as answered?

Comment: @moewe It might be better if you give a real answer from an expert. I was only guessing.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ok then, I typed up something below. Your guess was spot on though, and I dare say slightly more than a wild guess. If you change your mind I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat) points out [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514645/remove-space-between-authors-in-citation?noredirect=1#comment1301439_514645) it is enough to get rid of the two `\,`s in the definition of `multinamedelim`, since they add the space around the slash.

It should be noted that this modification of `biblatex-apa` no longer conforms to APA style and that I usually recommend not using `biblatex-apa` if you don't want APA style, since the style can be harder to customise because it is designed to implement APA guidelines as closely as possible.

Instead of the now deprecated `\labelnamepunct` it is usually nicer to redefine the context-sensitive `nametitldelim` for the `bib` context.

Finally, it should be noted that the code could be shortened by explicitly giving the values for `finalnamedelim` and `finalnamedelim:apa:family-given` instead of clearing them first and then using aliases. But even though the version with aliases is longer (and arguably looks clunkier - [I'll say that because I'm pretty sure I have used that idiom before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442298/35864)), I prefer it because it requires no repetition of the actual value `/` of the delimiters.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, maxcitenames=3, natbib=true, doi=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat*{multinamedelim}{/} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{multinamedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Goossens/Mittelbach/Samarin, 1994; Sigfridsson/Ryde, 1998]