# Citation format (Smith A., 2018)

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

I'm new to LaTeX.  I have already grasped the basics and I have already started working my thesis on it.  It is a very nice program to work with.  However, I am having a difficulty. I am unable to cite in the style which I'm looking for.  I have looked around and researched. There are tons of info out there, so much that it becomes very confusing.  Biber, `biblatex`, `natbib` and whatever else ... one can easily get lost in the process.  In the end, I'm still unable to cite in the style I need.

I need the cite in as in this example:

> 1. blabla bla bla (Smith A., 2018)
> 2. Smith A. (2018) has said blabla blabla

The nearest I'm getting with `biblatex` and `natbib` is: "(Smith 2018)"

I need the first letter of the first name after the surname and a comma before the year. In brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `biblatex` it is fairly straightforward to make a few changes to the standard `authoryear` styles to get close to what you describe.

The code is commented and it should be possible to look up the commands in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) if their names do not give enough hints as to what they do already.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% giveninits shortens all given names to initials
% autocite=inline gives 'inline' (\parencite) citations for \autocite
\usepackage[style=authoryear, autocite=inline, giveninits=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% names in "Family, Given" format
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}   % bibliography
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}  % citations

% no comma between family name and given initial:
% "Family G."
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

% comma between name and year in citation
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{sigfridsson}

\autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson E. and Ryde U., 1998)//Sigfridsson E. and Ryde U. (1998)//(Nussbaum M., 1978)//References//Nussbaum M. (1978). Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’. Princeton: Princeton University Press.//Sigfridsson E. and Ryde U. (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

For a general introduction into `biblatex` see [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864). The example above needs Biber, [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) tells you how you can set up your editor to run Biber.

Comment: The above does exactly what I asked.  
I need one more information.  How do I make it ommit name of several authors and print "and al.,(year)"



1.The earth is spherical in shape (Andrews and al., 2018)
2. Andrews and al. (2018) assumed that blablabla

Hoping to hear back

Comment: @NadeemMuhammad Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864