# Dealing with twins references (authoryear:Biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite two different papers that share the same author and were published in the same year. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[    backend=biber,
            style=authoryear,
            sorting=nyt,
            useprefix=true, 
            sortlocale=de_DE,
            natbib=true,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxcitenames=2, 
            maxbibnames=99,
            eprint=false]
            {biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{general.bib}
@article{giacometti16a,
author = "Giacometti, R. and Zavala, J.A. and Gog, L.",
year = {2016},
pages = {68-77},
title =  {Anthropogenic increase in carbon dioxide modifies plant–insect interactions},
journal = {Annals of Applied Biology},
volume={170},
number={1},
doi = {10.1111/aab.12319}
}
@article{giacometti16b,
author = "Giacometti, R. and Barneto, J. and Barriga, L. G and Sardoy, P.M. and Balestrasse, K. and Andrade, A.M and Pagano, E.A and Alemano, S.G and Zavala, J.A.",
title = {Early perception of stink bug damage in developing seeds of field-grown soybean induces chemical defences and reduces bug attack},
journal = {Pest Management Science},
volume = {72},
number = {8},
pages = {1585-1594},
keywords = {herbivory, jasmonic acid, MAPK signalling, plant–insect interactions, salicylic acid, Glycine max L, Nezara viridula L},
doi = {10.1002/ps.4192},
url = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ps.4192},
eprint = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/ps.4192},
year = {2016}
}
@article{thomma01,
title = "The complexity of disease signaling in Arabidopsis",
journal = "Current Opinion in Immunology",
volume = "13",
number = "1",
pages = "63 - 68",
year = "2001",
issn = "0952-7915",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/S0952-7915(00)00183-7",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0952791500001837",
author = "Thomma, B.P and Penninckx, I.A. and Cammue, C.P.  and Broekaert, W.F.",
keywords = "Arabidopsis thaliana, salicylic acid, jasmonic acid, ethylene, biotroph, necrotroph",
abstract = "Not more than 10 years ago it was generally accepted that pathogen-inducible defense mechanisms in plants are triggered through a central signaling cascade that regulates a multicomponent defense response. Now we know that the plant defense system is regulated through a complex network of various signaling cascades."
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{general.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

As is saying in \parencite{giacometti16a},  \parencite{giacometti16b} and in \parencite{thomma01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is how latex make my pdf:

[image]

As you may have noticed, when two paper share the same author and year, `biblatex` cites the first and second author (Giacomettis´s references) 
But I don't want to differentiate these twins references that way, I want only the first author to be cited and then the year with a letter "a" for the first paper and with a letter "b" for the second paper. Here is an example:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Add `uniquelist=false` to your `biblatex` options. Do you also want to remove *et al.*? You have removed it for Giacometti, but left it in for Thomma.

Comment: If you don't want to get rid of the "et al.", i.e. you want "Giacometti et al.", this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864. If you want to get rid of the et al. it would help if you could explain the rule behind deleting/keeping the "et al."

Comment: I forget to put "et al"  in Giacometti example because I put this manually. I mean, I want in this way: (Giacometti et al, 2016a) and (Giacometti et al, 201b)!

Comment: Then `uniquelist=false` as suggested by David and explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 should help you.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! Thanks moewe!

Comment: Very well. Can we close this as a duplicate, then?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Sorry for duplicate this question!

Comment: Please don't apologise for asking good duplicate questions. (Apart from the confusion about the "et al.") this was a very good question with clear MWE and explanations. The duplicate is *very* hard to find if you don't know the answer already or hit exactly the same search terms as the original question.

Comment: Thanks again! I really appreciate your contribution :)