# automatic replacement of 1+ authors with et. al. in citations in text

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have looked into multiple questions about this already, but none of the answers seems to work on my problem. I am using biblatex for referencing. When citing in text, i would like to have : (Author et. al. 2010). For now it is working for all my references, but for 2 or 3 articles.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxbibnames=20,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib} 
\printbibliography
```

and mybibliography.bib

```
@article{pinxten2017risk,
  title={At-risk at the gate: prediction of study success of first-year science and engineering students in an open-admission university in Flanders—any incremental validity of study strategies?},
  author={Pinxten, Maarten and Van Soom, Carolien and Peeters, Christine and De Laet, Tinne and Langie, Greet},
  journal={European Journal of Psychology of Education},
  pages={1--22},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

I want to get :

```
\parencite{pinxten2017risk}
```

> (Pinxten et al. 2017)

but instead i get:

```
\parencite{pinxten2017risk}
```

> (Pinxten, Van Soom, et al. 2017)

How can i fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code does not form a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe). I tested it the way I understood it and it works for me the way you want. So please provide a working MWE.

Comment: Is "Pinxten et al. 2017" perhaps ambiguous? Some styles do add additional information if there are multiple articles which would be cited the same way otherwise.

Comment: This is also true if the first author matches but not the second one and the date. In that case your style will print the first two authors for both keys plus the date. If the authors match completely but the dates don't then the style will only show the first author, though. So all in all this is expected behaviour (if you have two references from Pinxten).

Comment: From the information shown so far we can not be absolutely sure, but like Skillmon I would bet on `uniquelist` being the culprit. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.

Comment: Any news here? For all we know this is the same issue as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 and if there are no new developments here that suggest otherwise or point out issues with the solution presented there I'm going to vote to close this question as a duplicate in due time.

Comment: @Skillmon, yes you are right, "Pinxten et al. 2017" is ambiguous. `unniquelist` as suggested by @moewe solved my problem