# Unwanted random semicolon between some names in citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, harvard-style

I have a quite complicated template to write my thesis with, however there is a small issue that I cannot solve. The majority of the citations in my text (using ISO 690:2010 standard and the `biblatex-iso690` bibliography style) are fine, however some have an interesting issue with the authors' names.

Example of a good .bib entry:

```
@article{dewach06,
    ISSN = {00222879, 15384616},
    URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/3839071},
    author = {Hans Dewachter and Marco Lyrio},
    journal = {Journal of Money, Credit and Banking},
    number = {1},
    pages = {119--140},
    publisher = {[Wiley, Ohio State University Press]},
    title = {Macro Factors and the Term Structure of Interest Rates},
    volume = {38},
    year = {2006}
}
```

When referred in the text by `\textcite{dewach06}` prints *Dewachter et al. (2006)*. However:

```
@article{diebmac06,
    title = {The Macroeconomy and the Yield Curve: A Dynamic Latent Factor Approach},
    year = {2006},
    author = {Francis Diebold and Boragan Aruoba},
    institution = {National Bureau of Economic Research, Inc},
    type = {NBER Working Papers},
    number = {10616},
    url = {https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e876/92b94447574a05280cdf2e90ee1e77443a30.pdf}
}
```

when cited with the same function `\textcite` prints: *Diebold; Aruoba (2006)*.

I see no difference between the format of these two .bib entries, leaving only Diebold as an author works fine, adding another (third) author puts et al. after Auroba. I am clueless about this, and since my thesis should look nice, I need to fix this.

Comment: This has probably to do with `uniquelist`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.

Comment: I should note that `diebmac06` is probably not an `@article` but rather a `@report` (or `@techreport`). It is also unusual to abbreviate two authors to "Dewachter et al." I would find "Dewachter and Lyrio" much more natural since usually "et al." is taken to be plural.

Comment: Finally, and this is just my personal opinion, if you want your work to look nice I would not recommend the interpretation of ISO 690 in the norm itself (I am referring to the examples and their exact style, which is not prescriptive) and in `biblatex-iso` (which follows a stricter interpretation of the Czech version of the norm). ALL CAPS don't look very nice, the excessive use of semicolons and brackets for all kinds of information looks distracting ... The standard styles can be made far prettier with a few modifications.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I do need to follow the Czech citation style, since I'm studying at a uni in Czech rep. I have changed the bibtex arguments in one of the .sty files of the template, unfortunately it puts semicolon between two authors (i need to put "a", which means "and"). This is the code snippet from the .sty file:
`\thesis@require[backend=biber, style=\thesis@bibliography@style, sorting=\thesis@bibliography@sorting, autolang=other, sortlocale=auto, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}`

Comment: And the `thesis@bibliography@style` is defined as `\def\thesis@bibliography@style{#1}`

Comment: If the norm requires "and"/"a" instead of a semicolon, please open an issue at https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/issues. If you open an issue, please include a short example document that lets people reproduce the issue (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Ideally you would also reference the relevant bit of the norm.

Comment: Did my answer below help you? If not, could you comment why not? If it did help you, you may want to consider accepting it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I only put the two entries from the question into a document with `style=iso-authoryear` I get

> Dewachter et al., 2006; Diebold et al., 2006

in the citations. You say you get "Diebold; Aruoba (2006)" and that suggests that the `uniquelist` feature is involved (cf. [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864)). Presumably you have another entry where Diebold is also the first author, but that was not written by Diebold and Aruoba. (I faked such an entry for the example below.)

I personally find "Dewachter et al." for "Dewachter and Lyrio" unnecessary. Traditionally "et al." is seen as a plural abbreviation and should only replace two or more authors in a two-author list it may be slightly longer, but feels nicer, to also give the second author's name properly. I have no idea what your interpretation of ISO 690 has to say about that, but I could not find anything on this for citations in the English ISO 690. For the bibliography it only seems to be acceptable to use "et al." for lists of more than three authors (ISO 690:2010, 5.4.1 & 5.4.2).

I would also suggest to make `diebmac06` a `@report` entry and not an `@article`. There might be a small problem with that at the moment (see https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/issues/70), but semantically `@report` is the much better type here. An `@article` should absolutely have a `journal`.

---

Finally, to your question.

If you want to see

> Diebold a Aruoba (2006)

instead of

> Diebold; Aruoba (2006)

you need to tweak `finalnamedelim` and `multinamedelim`.

The MWE produces the same results as an unmodified `biblatex-iso` in the bibliography, but uses comma and "and" in the citations.

```
\documentclass[czech]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dewach06,
  ISSN      = {00222879, 15384616},
  URL       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/3839071},
  author    = {Hans Dewachter and Marco Lyrio},
  journal   = {Journal of Money, Credit and Banking},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {119--140},
  publisher = {[Wiley, Ohio State University Press]},
  title     = {Macro Factors and the Term Structure of Interest Rates},
  volume    = {38},
  year      = {2006}
}
@report{diebmac06,
  title       = {The Macroeconomy and the Yield Curve: A Dynamic Latent Factor Approach},
  year        = {2006},
  author      = {Francis Diebold and Boragan Aruoba},
  institution = {National Bureau of Economic Research, Inc},
  type        = {NBER Working Papers},
  number      = {10616},
  url         = {https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e876/92b94447574a05280cdf2e90ee1e77443a30.pdf}
}
@report{diebmac07,
  title       = {The Macroeconomy and the Yield Curve: A Dynamic Latent Factor Approach},
  year        = {2007},
  author      = {Francis Diebold and Aoragan Bruoba},
  institution = {National Bureau of Economic Research, Inc},
  type        = {NBER Working Papers},
  number      = {10616},
  url         = {https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e876/92b94447574a05280cdf2e90ee1e77443a30.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{dewach06,diebmac06,diebmac07}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> Dewachter et al., 2006; Diebold a Aruoba, 2006; Diebold a Bruoba, 2007

in citations and

> DIEBOLD, Francis; ARUOBA, Boragan, 2006. The Macroeconomy and the Yield Curve: A Dynamic Latent Factor Approach. Dostupné také z: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e876/92b94447574a05280cdf2e90ee1e77443a30.pdf. NBER Working Papers. National Bureau of Economic Research, Inc.

in the bibliography.

[image: Screenshot of the document just described.]

---

If you have reason to believe that the default behaviour of `biblatex-iso` goes against ISO 690, against the Czech or Slovakian translation of the norm or even only against a common interpretation of the norm, please open an issue at https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690/issues. Ideally you would include a full example document (not unlike the one in this answer) and could back up your claims about non-compliance with the norm with citations or exact references to certain clauses of the norm (or your interpretation of the norm).