# How can I shorten citations for two articles from the same year and mostly the same authors using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I use JabRef for my bibliography and implemented it the following way:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
maxnames=3,
citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

I have the following two citations from the same year (2019):

```
author = {Coppedge, Michael and John Gerring and Carl Henrik Knutsen
          and Staffan I. Lindberg and Jan Teorell and David Altman
          and Michael Bernhard and M. Steven Fish and Adam Glynn
          and Allen Hicken and Anna Lührmann and Kyle L. Marquardt
          and Kelly McMann and Pamela Paxton and Daniel Pemstein
          and Brigitte Seim and Rachel Sigman and Svend-Erik Skaaning 
          and Jeffrey Staton and Steven Wilson and Agnes Cornell
          and Lisa Gastaldi and Haakon Gjerløw and Nina Ilchenko
          and Joshua Krusell and Laura Maxwell and Valeriya Mechkova
          and Juraj Medzihorsky and Josefine Pernes
          and Johannes von Römer and Natalia Stepanova
          and Aksel Sundström and Eitan Tzelgov and Yi-ting Wang
          and Tore Wig and Daniel Ziblatt}
```

and

```
author = {Coppedge, Michael and John Gerring and Carl Henrik Knutsen
          and Staffan I. Lindberg and Jan Teorell and David Altman
          and Michael Bernhard and M. Steven Fish and Adam Glynn
          and Allen Hicken and Anna Lührmann and Kyle L. Marquardt
          and Kelly McMann and Pamela Paxton and Daniel Pemstein 
          and Brigitte Seim and Rachel Sigman and Svend-Erik Skaaning
          and Jeffrey Staton and Agnes Cornell and Lisa Gastaldi
          and Haakon Gjerløw and Valeriya Mechkova
          and Johannes von Römer and Aksel Sundtröm and Eitan Tzelgov
          and Luca Uberti and Yi-ting Wang and Tore Wig and Daniel Ziblatt}
```

Since the names are largely overlapping, the first article appears as

> Coppedge, Gerring, Knutsen, Lindberg,
>   Teorell, Altman, Bernhard, Fish, Glynn, Hicken, Lührmann, Marquardt, McMann,
>   Paxton, Pemstein, Seim, Sigman, Skaaning, Staton, Wilson, et al. (2019).

Is there a possibility to cite those as

> Coppedge et al. (2019a)

and

> Coppedge et al. (2019b)

instead (with the bibliography in accordance of course) or at least something similar without having to learn how to "code" my own bibliography? In my eyes it just doesn't look professional to have such long citations in a thesis.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864

Comment: adding "uniquelist=false" unfortunately doesn't change anything, even after recompiling the document several times. @moewe

Rather,
with

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
maxnames=3,
uniquelist=false,
citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

the document refuses to compile once I've closed it. If I delete "uniquelist=false" again the document works again.

Comment: Did you compile with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX after you changed the option? I just double-checked that `uniquelist=false` works with the name lists as given, see for yourself: https://gist.github.com/moewew/9eba4321b5f1aeede264a5ce9d0429fb If it does not work for you, please provide a complete, yet minimal example document that reproduces what you are seeing: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864

Comment: Did `uniquelist` work out for you in the end? If not, please consider adding a full example document that shows what you are doing and reproduces how the option does not work for you. If relevant, please include `.log` and `.blg` file output.

Comment: I just tried it again and now it works - haven't changed anything in between, just restarted the computer...