# How to truncate citations after first author?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

My citations should be in the format `Author et al., 20xx`. I understand from [prior answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex/69030) that it maybe because it is the first time citing a multiauthored manuscript in my text, but I don't see risks of ambiguity here in going with the `et al.` since the very first citation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style= authoryear-icomp, 
dashed=false,
citestyle=apa,
maxbibnames=1,maxcitenames=1,uniquelist=false,
sorting = nyt, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}


\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

Items that are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's book \parencite{einstein, einstein1} are physics related items. Next, a citation about \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}.

\medskip

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**simple.bib**

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@article{einstein1,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = "1973",
   chapter = "1.2",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@article{ctan,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
```

Comment: The `apa` style has quite strict rules for citing multiple authors. It's not intended as a style whose behaviour is designed to be modified. It might be better to use one of the standard `authoryear` styles instead.

Comment: I wanted to change it because, while the journal I am submitting to requires apa6, prior articles do not seem to have the full list of authors. But at this point, I'll follow your suggestion and leave it as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Usually* (that is to say with the standard styles), `maxcitenames=1` and `uniquelist=false` (see [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864)) should be more than enough to produce

> Author et al. 2000

for all citations with more than one author, but your situation is slightly more involved.

---

For medium-length name lists APA style wants to see all names on the first citation and "et al." only on a subsequent citation of the same work. See for example https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/11/the-proper-use-of-et-al-in-apa-style.html as well as the relevant passage in the APA manual.

`biblatex-apa` implements the requirements of the APA manual as closely as possible in `biblatex` and of course also implements this feature. Since `biblatex-apa` was specifically written to follow the APA rules it is not that easy and also not really recommended to change this behaviour.

The following suggestion is a bit of a hack

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, citetracker=false]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\let\blx@imc@ifciteseen\@firstoftwo
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann}

\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Aksın et al., 2006; Herrmann et al., 2006; Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//(Aksın et al., 2006; Herrmann et al., 2006; Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)]

---

In the MWE, however, you are already using a mixture of `biblatex-apa` and non-APA `biblatex` standard style `authoryear-icomp`, so I recommend you just ditch `biblatex-apa` completely.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp, 
  maxnames=1, uniquelist=false,
  dashed=false,
  natbib]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann}

\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,herrmann}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Aksın et al., 2006; Herrmann et al., 2006; Sigfridsson et al., 1998)//(Aksın et al., 2006; Herrmann et al., 2006; Sigfridsson et al., 1998)]

Note that `maxbibnames=1, maxcitenames=1,` can be simplified to `maxnames=1` and that `sorting=nyt` is already the default for `style=authoryear-icomp`. I would probably use `maxnames=2` or maybe even `maxnames=3` to avoid the slightly infelicitous "Sigfridsson et al." for "Sigfridsson and Ryde", this will still cut down lists longer than `maxnames` to `minnames` et al., but the short two- or three-author lists are left alone.