# Referencing by "et al."

Tags: biblatex, citing

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\parencite{halim2006}
```

will get:

> (Halim, Baig, and Bashir 2006)

---

**Q:** How to change from *"(Halim, Baig, and Bashir 2006)"*

to

> (Halim et al., 2006)

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example instead. Then we have an idea of what you are doing. Here it is anybodys guess.

Comment: edited my question.

Comment: Erh? Do you see anything in your question that others can copy and test as is, and get what you are complaining about? Neither can I. Please prepare a full but minimal example, that others can copy and work with as is. You list no document class, no preamble. Where does parencite come from? This low quality question is probably why you got a negative vote (not me, and I think it is rude not leaving a comment as to why one gives a negative vote).

Comment: thanks, i added, hopefully, is the correct way.

Comment: @user193541 ... Check this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/120578 ... if it solves your problem let us mark it as a dupplicate (`maxcitenames=2` is the option to be added while loading `biblatex` like `\usepackage[maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}`)

Comment: Can you copy what you have just written to a new empty file and get the output just just listed? People will pass on questions like this because they'll have to add a lot of data them self before they can even get something that compiles. Have a look at some other questions on the sure and see how they present their questions. Besides, the biblatex manual if the obvious place for you to look. It might also be an idea to tag the question with biblatex as it is mainly related to biblatex

Comment: Please make sure to read, understand, and follow https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. I think, this is what @daleif also would support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of names listed in the citation in the standard styles is controlled by the `maxnames` option and its correlates `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames`. By default it is set to 3, which means more than three names will appear with *et al.* but three or fewer will not.  So you can change this to be:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=2]{biblatex}
```

which will make name lists of three or more authors appear with *et al.*  You really shouldn't set it to 1 because it's inappropriate in all styles I know of to use *et al.* with only two authors.

If you want this only in the citation callouts and not the bibliography then you should set appropriate values for `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames` separately instead.

Comment: +1: Very good explanation.

Comment: Thanks. 'maxnames=2' works well!

Comment: @user193541 If this answer solved your problem, it's helpful to others to click on the checkmark icon beside the answer to accept it.

Comment: done, thanks. Previously i only put +1 mark