# BibLaTex: How to shorten list of author groups in cites to "et al."?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Consider the following situation:

- The same group of authors has published several documents
- Only the last author has changed over time

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
style=authoryear,%
natbib=true,%
maxcitenames=1,%
]{biblatex}%

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

    @article{Stiess.1996a,
        author = {Stiess, Roger and Mueller, Jacob and Else, Something},
        date = {1996},
    }

    @article{Stiess.1996b,
        author = {Stiess, Roger and Miller, Jan and Mueller, Jacob and Barding, Tom},
        date = {1996},
    }

    @article{Stiess.1999,
        author = {Stiess, Roger and Miller, Jan and Mueller, Jacob and Sutter, Jaqueline},
        date = {1999-10},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Stiess.1996a}
    \par\medskip
    \cite{Stiess.1996b}
    \par\medskip
    \cite{Stiess.1999}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

While the bibliography list looks completely fine, the citings inside the text body are way too long: While the first situation works fine with automatic adding `et al.`, I want the same thing to appear in the second and third citings as well (to compress the width of the citings).

How to do so?

Unfortunately `maxcitenames=1` does not work due to same author names.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex. tl;dr: add `uniquelist=false`. That will disable the disambiguation, so that all three papers are cited as "Stiess et al.".