# Apa style printer two authors in citation

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

I have a issue where my citation are including two authors if the author has multiple works in my bib file (irrespective of year).

e.g (Larsen, Tan, et al., 2013; Larsen, Thomassen, et al., 2014)
I would prefer (Larsen et al., 2013, 2014)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
natbib = true,
doi=true,
eprint = false,
url = false,
dashed=false,
%maxnames = 99,
apamaxprtauth = 99,
citestyle=authoryear-comp 
]{biblatex}


\bibliography{bib.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{Bray2018}. More text \citep{Biggs2008}, and more \citep{Larsen2013, Larsen2014}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

bib.bib

```
@article{Biggs2008,
author = {Biggs, James and Marsh, Sarah and Johnson, Simon and Walker, Steve. and Grover, Bob and Girolami, Mark and Mike, Sean},
journal = {Magic},
month = {may},
number = {5},
pages = {1--20},
title = {{No1. paper}},
volume = {4},
year = {2008}
}
@article{Bray2018,
author = {Bray, Yaya and Ferlay, George and Soerjomataram, Chris and Simons, Rebecca L. and Torre, Ahmedin},
journal = {CA},
month = {nov},
number = {6},
pages = {394--424},
title = {{No2. paper}},
volume = {68},
year = {2018}
}

@article{Larsen2013,
author = {Larsen, Max J and Tan, Steve and L{\ae}nkholm, Martin and S{\o}rensen, Thomas V O and Ejlertsen, Mads},
journal = {PloS},
month = {jan},
number = {5},
pages = {e64268},
title = {{No3. paper}},
volume = {8},
year = {2013}
}
@article{Larsen2014,
author = {Larsen, Max J and Thomassen, Martin and Andersen, Kyle and Kruse, Tim A and James, Anne-Marie},
journal = {Medical},
number = {9},
title = {{No4. paper}},
volume = {7},
year = {2014}
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to create the impression that the `Larsen 2013` and `Larsen 2014` pieces each have but a single author? Or do you maybe want the citation call-outs to be `Larsen et al. 2013` and `Larsen et al. 2014`?

Comment: You are right, I do want exactly what you suggested. Either `Larsen et al., 2013, 2014` or `Larsen et al., 2013; Larsen et al., 2014` is what I am after

Comment: What should be done if two multi-author paper whose first author is Larsen were published in the same year?

Comment: I would suggest using `Author et al., 1990a; Author et al., 1990b`. If that is used then the year in the bibliography would have to include the letter. I am open to other suggestions. I am okay with using the second author in citation in that instance also `Authour1, Author2 et al., 1990; Author1, Author3 et al., 1990`. I don't think I'll come across a situation where the first two authors and year are identical (hopefully)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with the setup in the question where you first have `style=apa,` but later overwrite the citation style with `citestyle=authoryear-comp` you don't actually have APA style citations.

If you want real APA style, your document should probably look more like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  apamaxprtauth=99,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Biggs2008,
  author  = {Biggs, James and Marsh, Sarah and Johnson, Simon
             and Walker, Steve and Grover, Bob and Girolami, Mark
             and Mike, Sean},
  journal = {Magic},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {1--20},
  title   = {No1. paper},
  volume  = {4},
  date    = {2008-05},
}
@article{Bray2018,
  author  = {Bray, Yaya and Ferlay, George and Soerjomataram, Chris
             and Simons, Rebecca L. and Torre, Ahmedin},
  journal = {CA},
  month   = nov,
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {394--424},
  title   = {No2. paper},
  volume  = {68},
  year    = {2018},
}
@article{Larsen2013,
  author  = {Larsen, Max J. and Tan, Steve and Lænkholm, Martin
             and Sørensen, Thomas V. O. and Ejlertsen, Mads},
  journal = {PloS},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {e64268},
  title   = {No3. paper},
  volume  = {8},
  date    = {2013-01},
}
@article{Larsen2014,
  author  = {Larsen, Max J. and Thomassen, Martin and Andersen, Kyle
             and Kruse, Tim A. and James, Anne-Marie},
  journal = {Medical},
  number  = {9},
  title   = {No4. paper},
  volume  = {7},
  year    = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \parencite{Bray2018}.
More text \parencite{Biggs2008},
and more \parencite{Larsen2013, Larsen2014}

Some text \parencite{Bray2018}.
More text \parencite{Biggs2008},
and more \parencite{Larsen2013, Larsen2014}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Some text (Bray, Ferlay, Soerjomataram, Simons, & Torre, 2018). More text (Biggs et al., 2008), and more (Larsen, Tan, Lænkholm, Sørensen, & Ejlertsen, 2013; Larsen, Thomassen, Andersen, Kruse, & James, 2014)//Some text (Bray et al., 2018). More text (Biggs et al., 2008), and more (Larsen et al., 2013; Larsen et al., 2014)]

Note how the first citation of each work uses the full author list (for up to six people), but subsequent citations use "et al.". Indeed `\parencite{Larsen2013, Larsen2014}` comes out as

> (Larsen et al., 2013; Larsen et al., 2014)

from the second citation onwards.

---

If you want to stick to the mixture of `style=apa,` and `citestyle=authoryear-comp,` and want to get rid of the disambiguation feature, you'll need `uniquelist=false`. See [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  citestyle=authoryear-comp,
  uniquelist=false,
  labeldate=year,
  apamaxprtauth=99,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Biggs2008,
  author  = {Biggs, James and Marsh, Sarah and Johnson, Simon
             and Walker, Steve and Grover, Bob and Girolami, Mark
             and Mike, Sean},
  journal = {Magic},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {1--20},
  title   = {No1. paper},
  volume  = {4},
  date    = {2008-05},
}
@article{Bray2018,
  author  = {Bray, Yaya and Ferlay, George and Soerjomataram, Chris
             and Simons, Rebecca L. and Torre, Ahmedin},
  journal = {CA},
  month   = nov,
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {394--424},
  title   = {No2. paper},
  volume  = {68},
  year    = {2018},
}
@article{Larsen2013,
  author  = {Larsen, Max J. and Tan, Steve and Lænkholm, Martin
             and Sørensen, Thomas V. O. and Ejlertsen, Mads},
  journal = {PloS},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {e64268},
  title   = {No3. paper},
  volume  = {8},
  date    = {2013-01},
}
@article{Larsen2014,
  author  = {Larsen, Max J. and Thomassen, Martin and Andersen, Kyle
             and Kruse, Tim A. and James, Anne-Marie},
  journal = {Medical},
  number  = {9},
  title   = {No4. paper},
  volume  = {7},
  year    = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \parencite{Bray2018}.
More text \parencite{Biggs2008},
and more \parencite{Larsen2013, Larsen2014}

Some text \parencite{Bray2018}.
More text \parencite{Biggs2008},
and more \parencite{Larsen2013, Larsen2014}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Some text (Bray et al. 2018). More text (Biggs et al. 2008), and more (Larsen et al. 2013, 2014)//Some text (Bray et al. 2018). More text (Biggs et al. 2008), and more (Larsen et al. 2013, 2014)]