# Citation of authors

Tags: biblatex, citing, csquotes

I have a and between 2 authors but when I have 3 authors I have a huge problem. I either use "author 1 et al" or "author 1, author 2, et al".

Can I use a citing style where when I have 2 authors I keep the two authors, while when I have 3 authors I have "author 1 and et al"?

What is really strange is that some citations have the exact style I want, but at least 1 citation has "author 1, author 2, et al"....

these are my options selected:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear, 
    uniquename=false, 
    giveninits=true, 
    maxbibnames=4, 
    maxcitenames=2,
    minbibnames=2,
    url=false,
    %isbn=false,
    doi=false
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: You need to add `uniquelist=false`.

Comment: ha yeah you are right. I noticed it quickly myself that why it is no longer in the question. Sorry for not logging my edit

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69030/87678 for details