# biblatex uses ambiguous citation keys with \citeauthor

Tags: biblatex, citing

According to [Set limit to one author when using "et al." in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/set-limit-to-one-author-when-using-et-al-in-biblatex) biblatex will ensure that a citation key is unique by expanding the author list.

In my document I use the default style. When I use `\citeauthor` biblatex will always truncate the author list to 1 author even if it isn't unique. Is there a way to ensure that biblatex will use the same behaviour as in the mentioned post with `\citeauthor`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% These options are based on a template
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=false,backrefstyle=three+,url=true,urldate=comp,abbreviate=false,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=20, uniquelist=true}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author = {Author, A. and Duthor, D. and E},
  year = {2001},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

According to \citeauthor{ABC01}  fact xy is true \cite{ABC01}.
However, \citeauthor{ADE01} mentions that there is some uncertainty \cite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: ambiguous author list]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on my version.... Could you please tell us what version of latex you are using...?

Comment: Indeed it is Biber 2.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `uniquelist=true,` (which your example already loads) is supposed to make the name lists (including those printed by `\citeauthor`) unique. Unfortunately, there is a bug in Biber 2.13 that prevents `uniquelist` from working properly if `uniquename` is not also set. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/924. This bug will be resolved in the next Biber release.

In the meantime you can add the option `uniquename=true,` as a workaround. Of course that means that you could also get initials to disambiguate people with the same family name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric
  maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=true, uniquename=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{ADE01,
  author = {Author, A. and Duthor, D. and E},
  year = {2001},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
According to \citeauthor{ABC01}  fact xy is true \cite{ABC01}.
However, \citeauthor{ADE01} mentions that there is some uncertainty \cite{ADE01}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: According to Author, Buthor, et al. fact xy is true [1]. However, Author, Duthor, et al. mentions that there is some uncertainty [2].]