# compiler collapsed using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have tried to change the way of citing multiple references from [1,2,3,4,5] to [1-5]. I have added a line `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}`, but the references just turned from numbers to names of authors and I got a lot of warnings. Then I have deleted this new command and the document just got plenty of errors and can't be compiled. I guess that something happened to the way the references were defined before this new command.

Please help me to return my document compilation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please visit tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx and tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ and consider to give a Minimal Example.

Comment: Have you tried to delete all the temporary files and recompile ?

Comment: When you change the style you may have to rerun Biber. Delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and compile again with the full LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle (where "LaTeX" stands for your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...).

Comment: Ah. I just saw your now deleted self-answer. I'm pretty sure that adding `\usepackage{cite}` is not actually what helped per se. It just forced you to go through the normal LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX compilation cycle, which made sure that the output is correct.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520649/35864