# biblatex cites too many names in text

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

The report I'm writing requires citations to be in authoryear style ie (Smith et al 1999.) except for cases where there are two authors in which case both names should be listed ie (Bloggs and Carlson 1998). To achieve this I'm using biblatex:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=apa, apamaxprtauth=20, sorting=nyt, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```

This works perfectly except for specific authors, in which case it lists extra authors for no apparent reason. These authors all have multiple papers cited in my report so I'm guessing that biblatex is thinking that they're different people, but in each case their name is written exactly the same in each entry in the .bib file. I've tried adding uniquename=false and that does nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You shouldn't mix citation and bib styles if you are using `biblatex-apa` which is designed to implement the exact APA style.  Either use `style=apa` or if that does things you don't like, just use `style=authoryear` which is a generic "APA" style. Also, instead of showing a code fragment, include the fragment into a compilable document that people can play with. In this case you should also show a couple of `.bib` item that produce the problem.

Comment: As Alan says I strongly recommend you do not mix `style=apa` and `authoryear`. `biblatex-apa` should only be used if you want to use APA style, in which case you want only `style=apa,` and nothing else. If you just want a generic author-year style `style=authoryear,` is the better choice because it does not have the quirks of APA style. Anyway, since you have `citestyle=authoryear,` this is essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864. You want `uniquelist=false,` (and quite possibly also `uniquename=false,`).

Comment: Did `uniquelist=false,` help you solve your problem? If not, can you prepare a full compilable code example that reproduces what you are seeing and shows how `uniquelist=false,` does not help you?