# Suppress author names in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

How can I create citation in the following format e.g (Victor et.all, 2019) using biblatex when having many author names?
I tried setting the maxnames in the \usepackage and it does not work.

Comment: You need to show what you tried to do when it didn't work so we can see what was wrong. Make a very short complete document that has a single cite and that doesn't give the result you want to have.

Comment: Any news here? We really need to know what you are trying and how it does not work for you. Without a short example document that tells us what is going on we won't be able to help you. My best guess at the moment is that this might have to do with the `uniquelist` option if `maxnames` does not (appear to) work (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864), but that's just a guess.