# Biblatex et al not working

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I have the problem that the shorting of authors in text citation is not working when I have two citations of the same first author. If I only cite one of the two, then it works properly.
Does anyone know what's the reason for this behaviour and how I can change it? I want et al. all the time.

Here I isolated the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} 
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
   autocite=inline,
   maxcitenames=2,
   maxbibnames=99,
   backend=biber, %--->führt (zeitweise?) zu fehler 
   dashed=false
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1} % - titel bleibt unverändert ... auch better bibtex checken wenn was nicht stimmt (export)
\addbibresource{references_promotion.bib}

%damit auch bei \citeyear, also ohne klammern der hyperref kommt
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {}
    {\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}



% Doppelpunkt nach dem Jahr im Literaturverweis
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

% Seitenangabe ohne automatischen Zusatz
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}
}


\begin{document}

\textcite{claussEinsatz2013}
\textcite{nidiekbe2019}
\textcite{nidiekNachschlag2020a}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Here is the bibtex:

```
@article{claussEinsatz2013,
  title = {Der Einsatz des iPads als Instrument in der Musiktherapie},
  author = {Clauß, Tobias and Seideneck, Mario and Gatzsche, Gabriel},
  date = {2013},
  journaltitle = {Musiktherapeutische Umschau},
  volume = {34},
  pages = {362--369},
  number = {4}
}

@incollection{nidiekbe2019,
  title = {be\_smart: Zur Bedeutung von Musik-Apps für die Teilhabe von Jugendlichen und jungen Erwachsenen mit komplexen Behinderungen an Kultureller Bildung},
  booktitle = {Forschung zur Digitalisierung in der Kulturellen Bildung},
  author = {Nidiek, Imke and Gerland, Juliane and Hülsken, Julia and Sieger, Marvin},
  editor = {Jörissen, Benjamin and Kröner, Stephan and Unterberg, Lisa},
  date = {2019},
  pages = {37--48},
  publisher = {kopaed},
  location = {München},
  langid = {german},
  series = {Kulturelle Bildung und Digitalität \#1}
}

@article{nidiekNachschlag2020a,
  title = {Nachschlag zu Heft 1/2020. Mehr Teilhabe an Kultureller Bildung durch digitale Musikinstrumente},
  author = {Nidiek, Imke and Gerland, Juliane and Hülsken, Julia},
  date = {2020},
  journaltitle = {Gemeinsam leben},
  volume = {2},
  pages = {123--128},
  number = {2}
}
```

[image: Here is how it looks like]

Comment: Do you mean abbreviating with "et al"? I think that only works for entries with the identical author list, not just the same first author. But maybe there is a special style that does this.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it is not possible to get the 'et al', when there are multiple combinations of authors with the same first author?

Comment: `biblatex` tries to avoid shortening different author list to the same short form. You can force that with the option `uniquelist=false,`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.

Comment: Did `uniquelist` help you solve the issue?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible: there may be a specific style add-on that does this, but you'd need to check them all out. But it sounds as if `uniquelist=false` will do the job. Or you of course write your own code to do it.