# Maxnames does not work when first names are identical

Tags: biblatex

I would like to print `et al.` after the first name when there are more than 2 authors. Therefore, I added `maxnames = 2` in the options of `biblatex`. However, when two papers have the same first two authors, `biblatex` prints every name. I suppose this is done so that the reader can distinguish the papers, but on the other hand, if the date is different, then that should be enough to distinguish them, and `biblatex` should print only the first name `et al.`.

In the example below, the first citation works well, but the two others don't because the first two authors are the same, even if the date is different. Is there a way to force `biblatex` to print `et al.` if the date is different?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = bwl-FU, maxnames = 2]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@article{doak_overweight_2000,
    title = {Overweight and {Underweight} {Coexist} within {Households} in {Brazil}, {China} and {Russia}},
    volume = {130},
    number = {12},
    journal = {The Journal of Nutrition},
    author = {Doak, Colleen and Adair, Linda and Monteiro, Carlos and Popkin, Barry},
    year = {2000},
    pages = {2965--2971},
}
@article{doak_dual_2005,
    title = {The dual burden household and the nutrition transition paradox},
    volume = {29},
    number = {1},
    journal = {International Journal of Obesity (2005)},
    author = {Doak, Colleen and Adair, Linda and Bentley, Margaret and Monteiro, Carlos and Popkin, Barry},
    year = {2005},
    pages = {129--136},
}
@article{popkin_dynamics_2020,
    title = {Dynamics of the double burden of malnutrition and the changing nutrition reality},
    volume = {395},
    number = {10217},
    journal = {The Lancet},
    author = {Popkin, Barry and Corvalan, Camila and Grummer-Strawn, Laurence M},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {65--74}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent \cite{popkin_dynamics_2020} \\ % works
\cite{doak_overweight_2000} \\
\cite{doak_dual_2005}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want the option `uniquelist=false`. By default `biblatex` avoids shorting different name lists to the same short form to avoid ambiguities. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.

Comment: thanks! I will validate this if you put it as an answer

Comment: Great! In that case it might be better to just close this question as a duplicate.