# Show only the first author if there are more than three authors

Tags: biblatex

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authortitle,sorting=nyt,dashed=false,%
    maxcitenames=2, uniquename=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

but i would like the two authors to be named in the text if there are two authors, and if there are more than two authors, i would like only the first author to be named and then et.al.
If I use the current setting, I get, for example

Huber and Meyer with a third author:
blablabl [Huber,Meyer et. al. 2000]

Huber and Meyer with no further author:
blablabl [Huber and Meyer 1997]

So how can I solve it so that Huber and Meyer is still displayed if there are only the two and if there are more not Huber, Meyer et. al. but only Huber et. al ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `[maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1]`.

Comment: Note that you may have to also add the option `uniquelist=false,` to stop `biblatex` from showing longer lists in case the shortened versions would be ambiguous. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.