# biblatex maxnames does not apply for certain bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I have difficulties with maxnames in my document. For some reason, two certain bibliography entries do not apply the maxnames option of biblatex. For every single other entry it works perfectly fine.

Despite a long time of figuring out, I am not able to see why those two entries do not trim the cited author list to 1, as intended.

I will provide a MWE with three entries: Entry 1 and entry 2 behave strangely and entry 3 behaves as intended.

Have I done something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, captions=tableheading, titlepage,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, dashed=false, maxnames=1, maxbibnames=8, minbibnames=8, firstinits=true, isbn=false, doi=false, eprint=false, date=year]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@Report{Sommer2019,
  author      = {Moritz Sommer and Dieter Rucht and Sebastian Haunss and Sabrina Zajak},
  date        = {2019},
  institution = {Institut für Protest- und Bewegungsforschung},
  title       = {Fridays for Future},
  number      = {2/2019},
  subtitle    = {Profil, Entstehung und Perspektiven der Protestbewegung in Deutschland.},
  titleaddon  = {ipb working paper},
}
@InBook{Sommer2020,
  author       = {Moritz Sommer and Sebastian Haunss and Beth Gharrity Gardner and Michael Neuber and Dieter Rucht},
  booktitle    = {Fridays for Future - Die Jugend gegen den Klimawandel.},
  date         = {2020},
  title        = {Wer demonstriert da?},
  booksubtitle = {Konturen der weltweiten Protestbewegung},
  editora      = {Sebastian Haunss and Moritz Sommer},
  location     = {Bielefeld},
  subtitle     = {Ergebnisse von Befragungen bei Großprotesten von \textit{Fridays for Future} in Deutschland im März und November 2019.},
}
@Article{Hedenus2014,
  author       = {Fredrik Hedenus and Stefan Wirsenius and Daniel J. A. Johansson},
  date         = {2014},
  journaltitle = {Climatic Change},
  title        = {The importance of reduced meat and dairy consumption for meeting stringent climate change targets},
  doi          = {10.1007/s10584-014-1104-5},
  number       = {1-2},
  pages        = {79--91},
  volume       = {124},
  publisher    = {Springer Science and Business Media {LLC}},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Test\autocites{Sommer2019, Sommer2020, Hedenus2014}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Check in the documentation the options uniquenames and uniquelist

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864

Comment: Great tips, thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think it makes a material difference, but note that `fontspec` can only be used with the Unicode engines LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. This means that the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is pretty much pointless, since these engines always assume UTF-8 input (in fact even for pdfLaTeX `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can be dropped now, since it has been the default for more than 3 years now). Note however, that there are packages that many people used to load with pdfLaTeX that should not be used with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` comes to mind).

Comment: The `biblatex` option `firstinits` was renamed to ` giveninits` more than five years ago. Switch from `firstinits=true,` to `giveninits=true,`. Setting `maxnames` to one value and then immediately setting `maxbibnames` to another is equivalent to setting `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames`, which is slightly more informative here, I'd say.