# How to change the number of authors before et al.?

Tags: biblatex

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inlinetext}{\textcite}{\textcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=inlinetext}
 \addbibresource{test.bib}




 \title{A}
     \author{B}
      \date{\today}

        \begin{document}

        \maketitle
      \autocite{jia2019efficient}
      \autocite{jia2019towards}

     \end{document}
```

The content of the bib file is as follows:

```
   @article{jia2019efficient,
   title={Efficient task-specific data valuation for nearest neighbor algorithms},
   author={Jia, Ruoxi and Dao, David and Wang, Boxin and Hubis, Frances Ann and Gurel, 
 Nezihe Merve and Li, Bo and Zhang, Ce and Spanos, Costas J and Song, Dawn},
   journal={VLDB},
   year={2019}
  }

@article{jia2019towards,
  title={Towards efficient data valuation based on the shapley value},
  author={Jia, Ruoxi and Dao, David and Wang, Boxin and Hubis, Frances Ann and Hynes, 
Nick and G{\"u}rel, Nezihe Merve and Li, Bo and Zhang, Ce and Song, Dawn and Spanos, 
Costas J},
  journal={AISTATS},
  year={2019}
}
```

The authors of two papers are similar but not exactly the same, so the display I got is that 5 authors are listed in the citations to distinguish them. I prefer to have Jia et al. (2019a) and Jia et al. (2019b) instead. How can I make it?

Comment: `uniquelist=false,` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 for more details.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I tried this but the reference list becomes et al. too...

Comment: If you want all names in the bibliography add something like `maxbibnames=999,`.

Comment: @moewe It works. Thank you very much!