# Biblatex Error when Compiling - two papers with overlapping authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, author

I have been using Latex online through Overleaf for a while now. I use Biblatex to do compile my Bibliographies.

In the last document, I've encountered the following problem.

I need to reference two papers. One is authored by Gilat (name) Levy (surname) and Ronny (name) Razin (surname). Another that has the same two authors plus Ines (name) Moreno de Barreda (surname).

I need the references to appear as Levy and Razin (year) and Levy et al. (year). Therefore, I put the following options when I called the package Biblatex (see screenshot). Also I called as usual my Bib file.

[image: calling bib file]

Here's a screenshot of the bib file. Everything seems fine to me and correct.

[image: the bib file]

Still, when compiling, I get the following

[image: correct]
[image: incorrect]

Levy and Razin (year) is good, but I get Levy, Barreda, et al. (year), instead of Levy et al. (year).

Changing the author input in the bib file, I still get the same error, or similar errors.

For instance, if in the bib file I change the format to

Surname author 1, Name author 1, and Surname author 2, Name author 2 , etc.

I get Levy, Moreno de Barreda, et al. (year), which is still incorrect.

Clearly there's some confusion as the same two authors appear in both papers. Yet, it shouldn't be like that.

I tried to change the author part of the bibfile for the Levy et al. (2022) paper many times.

I changed to the format Levy, Gilat, and Moreno de Barreda, Ines, and Ronny Razin and to many many variations thereof. Still, I always get an incorrect outcome when I compile.

I put {} around Moreno de Barreda as the software might be confused about the three-words surname but nothing changed.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please add a small, but compilable test file to your question. Please add it as text and not as images so people can copy it to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You might want to check the biblatex documentation for "uniquename"  and similar options.

Comment: Please do not post code as pictures. Pictures are next to useless for us if we want to recreate what you did, because we have to manually re-type the text on the picture. Instead copy the code directly as text and mark it up as code. Please post a fully compilable example document starting with `\documentclass` and containing `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that reproduces what you are seeing with as little code as possible.

Comment: That all said, I guess that `uniquelist` (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864) is what you want here, but I haven't tested it, because I did not want to re-type the `.bib` entries from the screenshot.

Comment: Great it worked, thanks! Next time I'll type the question better.