# Cite the name of authors correctly with more than 3 letters using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am using the following package for the bibliography on Overleaf:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle = numeric, citestyle=authoryear, citecounter, natbib, labelnumber, uniquename=false, maxbibnames  = 2, maxcitenames = 2]{biblatex}
```

Although this generates a problem.

For instance, when I have authors whose surname is more than 3 letters, such as:

```
@article{Zangaga023,
  title={...},
  author={Zangaga, Ausperin and Westminster, Christine and Lebronne, Mangue},
  journal={Journal of ...},
  volume={2},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group UK London}
}
```

When I use `\textcite`, I correctly get

```
"Zangaga et al. (2023)"
```

So there's nothing wrong.

However, if an author has a surname with less than 4 letters, e.g.:

```
@article{Wu02spatio,
  title={...},
  author={Xu, Jiajun and Wang, Jinchao and Li, Rui and Yang, Xiaojun},
  journal={Journal of ...},
  volume={2},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group UK London}
}
```

I get

```
"Xu, Wang, et al. (2023)"
```

instead of

```
"Xu et al. (2023)"
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is due to the `uniquelist` feature https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 and has nothing to do with the number of letters in the name: just with whether or not different name lists would abbreviate to the same "... et al.".